# Classic ASP to Wordpress migration

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, asp-classic

I have a Wordpress install on a domain, and I am setting up my rewrite rules now. The old site runs on asp and the new site php.

These are my rules, which I am inserting manually into htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^news_details.asp?id=([^/0-9]+)$ turkey-property-news/index.php?old_id=$1
RewriteRule ^property_([0-9]+).asp$ turkey-real-estate/index.php?old_id=$1
RewriteRule ^links1.asp?id=([0-9]+)$ index.php?post_type=sbdirectory&old_id=$1
```

The middle one works, the other 2 don't. turkey-property-news and turkey-real-estate are actual directories with an index.php running a custom query, whereas the last rule uses the core wordpress functionality.

As mod_rewrite is not my mastermind chosen subject I was hoping to get some help here.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a useful error description. What happens or doesn't happen when you visit those URLs?

Comment: Basically the url rewrite isn't affected, the server process the original news_details.asp?id= etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query strings (the bit after the ?) are not part of a URL; you can filter on them using a rewriteCond statement. Something like this:

```
rewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([^/0-9]+)$ 
rewriterule ^news_details.asp$ turkey-property-news/index.php?old_id=%1
```